# how to append # at the end of number in phonecall function android

Tags: android

my code is :

```
    x="*141#"; 
    String phoneCallUri =("tel:" + x);
    Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
    startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
```

when phone call function is called it does not use # only *141 is called.Please help me out 
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

You should change the second line to : `String phoneCallUri = "tel:" + Uri.encode(x);`

Answer (score 1):

`#` has spatial meaning in Uri so you have to encode it. Correct this like that:

```
x="*141#"; 
String phoneCallUri =("tel:" + Uri.encode(x));
Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
```

---

Edit:
Or better approach:

```
x="*141#";
Uri  uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", x, null);
Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
phoneCallIntent.setData(uri);
startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
```